# Django, how to get the time until a cookie expires

Tags: django, session, cookies, session-cookies

Before marked as dup (I believe many answers are incorrect becase):
According to my research:

- `request.session.get_expiry_age` returns the TOTAL lifespan of the cookie, not the time from now until it expires. It always returns the same value, irrespecitive of how much time is left.
- Similarly `get_expiry_date` adds the total lifespan to the now time. It always increases when called.
  Hence niether of them help.

`settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` refreshes the cookie on every request, this is NOT what I am trying to achieve.

`get_session_cookie_age()` ONLY returns the value of settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE, as seen in the sourcecode:

```
def get_session_cookie_age(self):
    return settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE
```

I use the `cached_db` session back end. The cached part is made none in void because it has to save the cookie everytime, hence `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` is not applicable. The reason I ask this question is because I wish to refresh a cookie ONLY if the time left has gone below a threshold, and hence have some hysterious (have the benefits of caching and auto refreshing).

Here is my code that does not work because of the behaviour of `get_expiry_age`/`get_expiry_date` as explained above:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class SessionExpiry(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        """Automatically refresh a session expirary at a certain limit.

        If request.session age goes below settings.SESSION_REFRESH, then
        set the sessions expirary age to settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE. The
        session is not refreshed every time to have the caching benefits of
        the cached_db backend.
        """
        try:
            empty = request.session.is_empty()
        except AttributeError:
            return None
        if (empty or not getattr(settings, 'SESSION_REFRESH', None)):
            return None
        if request.session.get_expiry_age() < settings.SESSION_REFRESH:
            request.session.set_expiry(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)
        return None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an area of Django that's confusing, in both design and documentation. The easiest way to figure out what's going on is to look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4376c2c7f8cd9c7604a7d053b3c4022dd5ac2795/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L246).

To get what you want you need to set a custom expiration as a `datetime`. If you use seconds (including the default `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`) that is interpreted as the number of seconds from *now*; that is, from whenever you ask.

So to set the expiration, use:

```
# Using timedelta will cause the session to save the expiration time as a datetime.
request.session.set_expiry(timedelta(seconds=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE))
```

If you do that, calls to `get_expiry_age()` will return the actual difference between the current datetime and the datetime set as the expiry.

Be sure to note the warning in the [`set_expiry()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry) documentation: "Note that `datetime` and `timedelta` values are only serializable if you are using the `PickleSerializer`."

Comment: You are smarter than I, I did look at the sourcecode, but could not figure out the arguments, it seemed like circular dependencies to me, pass in the expiry data to get the expiry data. Thanks so much, that is brillant!

Comment: Just change `timedelta(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)` to `timedelta(seconds=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)` so I can mark as right answer please (or else the timedelta is set in days). (edit que is full)

Comment: Although this works during debug mode, when django tries to save the session (`request.session.save()`) it generates the response `Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: Because JSON is not pickle.

Comment: I just waved the white flag and use `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`, doesn't seem worth it to hack it so much.

Answer (score 2):

Came here from the Django ticket. Here is what I came up with avoiding the need for pickle serializer and SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST. So instead of using the `datetime` we can use plain timestamp, and since `set_expire` does not support that, we will just add another session key to store that.

```
class RefreshSessionMiddleware(middleware.SessionMiddleware):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        session = request.session
        if not (session.is_empty() or session.get_expire_at_browser_close()):
            expiry = session.get('_session_expire_at_ts')
            now_ts = int(time.time())
            cookie_lifetime = session.get_expiry_age()
            if expiry is None or now_ts + cookie_lifetime / 2 > expiry:
                # This will set modified flag and update the cookie expiration time
                session['_session_expire_at_ts'] = now_ts + cookie_lifetime

        return super().process_response(request, response)
```

Comment: Just tested this and it works very well, well done!! You seem to be the only person who understands how django expiry works.